# Java Files.exists() returns false even if the file exists

Tags: java, web, server, webserver

I'm doing a web server and it has to read a txt config file and to assign a port number, directory, the default index.html file, etc, but when it checks for the index.html it keeps saying it doesn't exist even though the file does exist.

The txt file contains this:

```
port=80
directory=c:\www
index=index.html
listing=true
connexions=5
```

I checked the files permissions and it doesn't seem to be blocked.
I tried both `.exists()` and `getAbsoluteFile().Exists()`and both return false
Here if the code for reading in the file:

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(config));

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        tokens = line.split("=");
        if(tokens.length > 1) {
            switch (tokens.length) {
                case 0:
                    if (Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) < 65535) {
                        portNumber = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                        param++;
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("Port in config file is invalid.");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    File check = new File(tokens[1]);
                    if (check.getAbsoluteFile().exists()) {
                        rootPath = path ? args[1] : tokens[1];
                        param++;
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("Specified directory doesn't exist in config file");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    File checkFile = new File(rootPath + "\\" + tokens[1]);
                    if (checkFile.getAbsoluteFile().exists()) {
                        indexFile = tokens[1];
                        param++;
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("Index file in config file doesn't exist.");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (tokens[1].toLowerCase().equals("true") || tokens[1].toLowerCase().equals("false")) {
                        list = tokens[1].equals("true");
                        param++;
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("Can't validate the list parameter in config file.");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) > 0) {
                        connNumber = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                        param++;
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("Number of connexions in config file is invalid.");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        else{
            System.err.println("Missing arguments in config file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: could you please post the value of the file path directly before doing check.getAbsoluteFile().exists()? Maybe its just a failure in formatting the path

Answer (score 0):

since you are developing web app you must identify the resource folder in the first place and insure that the file you trying to access is on that directory.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("file/test.xml").getFile());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mess.

`switch` statement on `tokens.length` with `case 0`, followed by `tokens[1]`. If `tokens.length == 0` then `tokens[1]` will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Actually, with the `if (tokens.length > 1)` before the `switch`, it cannot ever enter `case 0` and `case 1`. Besides, all 5 lines in your file has 2 tokens, so **it will enter `case 2` for all lines**.

With first line being `port=80`, it will look for file `<rootPath>\80`, which is unlikely to exist.

*Hint:* The value of `tokens[0]` means something. You should probably use it.